# Egg curve constant width.

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to derive a formula for a very particular egg curve.
It should be taller on one side of the origin, but a line drawn from one side to the other passing through the origin should have a constant length regardless of the angle of the line.

For reference the data points below should help understand the shape.

0deg, x=0, y=10
45deg, hypotenuse=11
90, x=-12, y=0
135deg, hypotenuse =13
180deg, x=0, y=-14
270deg, x=12, y=0

As the data above shows, in this example the length any line drawn from one side to the other through the origin is always constant (24).

However I can't figure out how to make it work, I'm trying from sin\cos but they're always symmetric about 0... And an offset won't work as it needs to be 0 at 90 degrees.

Comment: I don't know if the figure you need does exist: I'm finding only cardioid-like curves.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your figure, is it correct that your "0deg" is what convention would normally call $90$ degrees and that the radius of the figure increases linearly from $10$ to $14$ as the angle goes from $0$ to $180$ degrees?

Comment: Writing the curve in polar form, it seems that the desired condition is that $r(\theta)+r(\theta+\pi)$ be independent of $\theta$. But we also need $r(\theta)>0$ for all $\theta$ and (more importantly) $r(\theta+2\pi)=r(\theta)$ for all $\theta$. There is one obvious solution $r(\theta)=$const., corresponding to a circle at the origin; the question is what others exist.

Comment: Following that idea, it looks like polar curves of the form $r(\theta)=a-b\cos\theta$ should work if $a>2b>0$. (If $0<a<2b$, then the curve will bow inward at $\theta=0$ and therefore look more like a cardiod than an egg; this is consistent with @N74's remark above.)

Comment: This came up as a suggestion on my own question.  I found $F\left(\theta\right)=\frac{\left|\theta-\pi\right|}{\pi}$ gives a palm-leaf shape with constant width through the origin.  It's as close as I can get to your problem.